# How do I access sub-directories (t, scripts) in my module's root installation directory?

Tags: perl, perl-module

Module Foo::Bar has been installed somewhere in `@INC`.

Other than recursively checking `@INC` for `Foo`, then `Bar`, then `scripts` or `t`, is there a way of accessing those directories *from the module itself*?

For example, I would like to call a particular script in `lib/scripts/findmeifyoucan.pl` from `Foo/Bar.pm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it relative to the related code, by using `%INC` to find where the related code lives:

```
package Foo::Bar;
# this code lives in ...something.../lib/Foo/Bar.pm

package Unrelated;

use File::Spec;
use Foo::Bar;

my $filename = 'Foo/Bar.pm';
(my $libpath = $INC{$filename}) =~ s#/\Q$filename\E$##g; ## strip / and filename
my $script = File::Spec->catfile($libpath, qw(scripts findmeifyoucan.pl));
```

Comment: That's great, thanks. One other question: I'm using Module::Build, and none of the `scripts` or `t` directories show up there. I suppose I need to configure `Build.pl` to install those as well? Or are they installed to another location, other than the source directory?

Comment: @Pedro: I can't say for certain; I haven't used that lib for quite a while. I think a similar question may have been asked here, though (or you can ask it yourself as a new one).